# Proof verification request: $g(z)=\cos(\sqrt{z})-z$ has infinitely many zeroes in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Looking for proof verification.

Suppose that g has only $n<\infty$ zeroes. Since $g$ is entire (it's power series has infinite radius of convergence), we can apply Jensen's formula:

$$1=\log|g(0)|=\sum^n_{k=0} \frac{|a_k|}{r} + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 \log|g(re^{i\theta})|d\theta$$

On the disc $D(0,r)$. Now, let $r$ become very large. Then, I claim that $\sum\rightarrow\epsilon$ for a small $\epsilon$ if and only if $n$ is finite. Since $g$ is entire, $\sup|a_k|<\infty$ where $a_k$ are the zeroes of $g$, and moreover $\sup|a_k|=\infty$ if and only if $n=\infty$.

Now we have that

$$2\pi \approx \int^{2\pi}_0 \log|g|$$

Hence $|g|\approx c$ for a constant c independent of our choice of $r$. We can finally let $r\rightarrow\infty$, and $|g|\rightarrow c$. But clearly $|g|$ is not constant thus we have a contradiction.

And moreover if $\sum\rightarrow C_1\neq 0$ for some constant $C_1$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$, then $\log|g|$ may not be constant on $D$. I say this because I am trying to make sure that, in the case where $n=\infty$ this proof does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Well, $\log|g(0)|=0$ in your case. So Jensen's formula leads to $0 \approx \int^{2\pi}_0 \log|g|$, which does not help in controlling $|g|$.

Comment: Right. How do you use the formula then to prove this?

Comment: You have $2\pi \approx \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log(|g(re^{i\theta})|) \text{ }d\theta$ when $r$ is large, but this does not mean that $|g(z)| \approx c$ for $|z|$ large (here $c$ is some constant).